# Modeling and query on many to many models with through

Tags: django, django-models

I thought about using the custom through to record the comments that users makes on objects and record the date in addition to the comment text. I tried to build this model but I think it's wrong. It's my first time with M2M rel.

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Obj(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)    

class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    comment = models.ManyToManyField(Obj, through='Comments')

class Comments(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    obj = models.ForeignKey(Obj, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    data = models.DateTimeField()
    text = models.CharField(max_length=500)
```

I would like to make queries based on the object id that can get
any comments made on that item, the username and date for each of them.

Also doing this query  `qs=Comments.objects.all()`    returns empty queryset

EDIT:
As it was suggested I tried this query:

```
var = Comments.objects.filter('object__id = 1').values('text', 'data')
```

I get an error:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/er/

Django Version: 3.1.5
Python Version: 3.9.0
Installed Applications:
['ER',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\paren\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\paren\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\paren\OneDrive\Documenti\Programmazione\Django\2\db\ER\views.py", line 9, in index
    var=Comments.objects.filter('obj__id=1').values('text','data')
  File "C:\Users\paren\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\paren\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 942, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\paren\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 962, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone._filter_or_exclude_inplace(negate, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\paren\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 969, in _filter_or_exclude_inplace
    self._query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\paren\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1358, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "C:\Users\paren\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1377, in _add_q
    child_clause, needed_inner = self.build_filter(
  File "C:\Users\paren\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1255, in build_filter
    arg, value = filter_expr

Exception Type: ValueError at /er/
Exception Value: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Comment: Everything appears correct. Have you created any comment instances?

Comment: How do I do that? So far I've done query in this kind : Models.objcets.all/filter().

Comment: Create comments to test your query. If you want all the comments of a specific object use: Comments.objects.filter(obj_id= id_you_want)